# objective c when click on tableview, cells disappear

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

I am new to objective c, and trying to figure out uitableview. I added two cells to tableview, when I click any area of the tableview, two cells disappear or labels get deleted. I am not sure. how can I fix this?

here is how I add two cells

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}

if(indexPath.row==0)
    cell.textLabel.text=@"test 1";
else if (indexPath.row==1)
    cell.textLabel.text=@"test 2";
// Configure the cell...

return cell;
}

 - (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
 { 
  return 1;
  }

 - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
 {
  return 5;
 }
```

I have given the sections and rows

Comment: paste your complete code with delegate as well as datasource methods..

Comment: there is no datasource or delegates. I am new to objective c :)

Comment: first you need to set the number of rows in your table then you can define the cell for each row in cellForAtIndexPath

Comment: with no datasource, how do you tell the tableview how much rows it contains?

Comment: I added the code where I give the number of rows and sections

Comment: so these are data source methods

Comment: sorry, I didnt know they were called datasources

Comment: you need to tell number of rows (its mandatory method) if data source is not available then you should return some number hard coded ....

Comment: so paste didSelectRow.. which is delegate method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

Your highlighted label text color may be white and looks like disappeared. Add this line on your cellForRow at indexpath mthod and check

```
[cell.textLabel setHighlightedTextColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
```

Best Regards.